# Run mongodump when network is interrupted

Tags: mongodb

if I run `mongodump` on a database from a remote host and in the middle of the process the network connection is interrupted for some time... if I start `mongodump` again will it continue from where it finished or will it start from the very beginning?

same question about `mongorestore`

Comment: Were you able to figure out if mongodump is resumed or restarted if reran after network interruption?

Answer (score 2):

For mongodump, you can do it manually by splitting your bson file, here is the bson format documentation http://bsonspec.org/.

Say you have 90% percent done of a 10000bytes file:

1. Calculate the size of leftover data in bytes, which is 1000bytes in this case.
2. Get a overview of the border line area by `tail -c 1200 $collection.bson | head -c 500 | xxd`, use 1200 just to be safe, otherwise some documents might be missing.
3. Find the beginning of a new document in the output of xxd, this can be tricky, the beginning of a document is a 32bit variable which describes the size of that document, read the bson documentation if you're not sure what to do.
4. Say the offset of a new document according to xxd is 66, then 1134 (1200-66) is the size of your leftover data.
5. `tail -c 1134 data.bson | mongorestore -d $db -c $col -`

Answer (score -4):

It will continue backing up/restoring from the position it was interrupted at, providing that you use exactly the same directory for backup/restore.

It's a good practice to run such jobs in a [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session, so that no network interruption can affect them.

Comment: Is this true for `mongorestore`? I had one that I inadvertently CTRL-Ced when I thought the shell had frozen, but when I "resumed" it it started at the beginning and is printing out duplicate key errors (which is fine, eventually it will catch up and complete). I did do it in a new shell (inside of screen... for obvious reasons) but same directory. Note also that I dumped from a local mongo instance and am restoring to another host over the network. Running 3.0.3 I believe

Comment: This is not true, it starts again.

Comment: Running this job in screen session would not help since the OP has mentioned that the database is in remote host.